# 4.13 kernels will not boot in ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I recently installed xubuntu 16.04.3 on a Dell e6430 laptop,  Kernel 4.10.0.42 boots fine but subsequent updates (4.13.0.x of which there have been 3) will not boot and kick me back to grub menu.  I've removed the 4.13 kernels via synaptic and updated grub to set the 4.19.0.42 kernel as current so I can boot the machine.  Can't find anything on Launchpad that seems similar - what can I do now?

Comment: sorry, current kernel should read "4.10.0.42"

Comment: Found a Launchpad bug for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1742675  I will continue running 4.10.0.42 and installing 4.13 updates as I receive them.  Hoping for a timely fix...